# Cordova clean failed to execute, problem with Android SDK Platform 27

Tags: android, cordova, ionic3, apk

### Ionic release apk

I launched cordova clean but it does not work!!!

I did:

## sdkmanager --licenses

but I still have the same problem!!!

File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /opt/android/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.

  > You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  >   [Android SDK Platform 27].
  >   Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  >   Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

who have the result please ?!!

Comment: are you able to run this cordova project into device before generating release APK?

Comment: No, I tried to lunch cordova clean but I get File /root/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded. Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /opt/android/licenses Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. as a return

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall the SDK build tools 27.